# Cannot add a bounty to question - getting a 404 page when I try

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounty

I am trying to add a bounty to [this question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29202584/3991344), but when I do so I get a 404 page.

What I am doing is clicking "Start a bounty", then selecting 50, then "Authoritative reference needed", and then entering the following message (though I've used several different ones and they've all failed):

> `While both Makoto and eckes wrote good answers, it seems like it is not clear whether the cases where they state are the *only* ones that throw IOErrors, and whether other cases exist that can cause IOErrors in other filesystem methods.  An authoritative source providing this information would be useful.`

I then hit "Start bounty", and am transported to [this 404 page](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/bounty/start/29202584).  No bounty is posted and no reputation is deducted.

Comment: same bug report [on meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252002/bounties-broken-network-wide)